# Ionic: set Ionic-scroll pinch to canvas

Tags: canvas, ionic-framework

Here is atypical task.

We have `ionic-scroll` directive and canvas element inner. We can scroll and zoom it, and we have coordinates as object `{ left: X, top: Y, zoom: Z }` with `$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle`

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" min-zoom="-2" class="ionic-scroll"  delegate-handle="image">
    <canvas id="photo"></canvas>
</ion-scroll>
```

How can I set this params to canvas image at `context.drawImage()` ?

I tried to use `canvas.scale(zoom, zoom)` but it doesn't works

Comment: You have `canvas.scale` but the drawing is via the 2D api the same as `context.drawImage()` so call `context.scale(zoom,zoom);` BTW  a conventional name for the context variable is `ctx` just handy, reduces these types of mistakes, but not important.

Comment: @Blindman67 yes, I didn't describe why `scale` doesn't works.
The reason is different zoom. Ionic has own zoom (I don't know how it counts) and it consist at 1 number. 
Canvas has two params with zoom - `scalewidth` and `scaleheight` 
So when Ionic has 1.8356 zoom value, Canvas has different position  at (1.8356, 1.8356)

Comment: OK I have never used Ionic so don't know how to help. I assume that scalewidth and scaleheight are attributes added by Ionic as the Canvas element does not have those attributes. With luck someone that knows Iconic will see your problem and get you on your way.